# Typsetting a variant of division

Tags: equations

In Oliver Salazar Celis' "Adaptive Thiele interpolation," *ACM Communications of Computer Algebra* ***56***(3), Issue 221, September 2022, page 125 (Eq. 1) we find:

[image: ACM equation]

How does one typeset the vertical plus horizontal notation (note that the straight segments *touch*)?

And what does this notation mean?

Comment: This looks like a continued fraction.

Comment: Google or others give: *"an algorithm generates a Thiele-Werner continued fraction representation of the interpolant"*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple `array` could do the trick, but I have no idea about what it means. First time I see something like that.

**Update:** added the `array` package for better rules connections, as suggested in the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % better connections between the rules (see egreg's comment)
\usepackage[textwidth=15cm]{geometry}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myfrac}{mm}{\begin{array}{c|}#1\\\hline\multicolumn{1}{|c}{#2}\end{array}}

\begin{document}
\[
C_n(x) = \varphi_0[x_0] + \myfrac{x-x_0}{\varphi_1[x_0,x_1]} +
                          \myfrac{x-x_1}{\varphi_2[x_0,x_1,x_2]} +
                          \myfrac{x-x_2}{\cdots} +
                          \myfrac{x-x_{n-1}}{\varphi_n[x_0,\ldots,x_n]},
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.  (accept)  Now I'll post on math.SE to see what it means!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork you will need `\newcommand` not `\NewDocumentCommand` for mathjax.

Comment: You should also load `array` in order to improve the connections between the rules.

Comment: @egreg, done!! Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 6):

Using `holtpolt` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{holtpolt}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[C_n(x) = \varphi_0[x_0] +\polter{x-x_0}{\varphi_1[x_0,x_1]}+\polter{x-x_1}{\varphi_2[x_0,x_1,x_2]}+\polter{x-x_2}{\ldots}+\polter{x-x_{n-1}}{\varphi_n[x_0,\ldots,x_n]}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks...  helpful indeed.